# Visual Studio 2008 devenv running application, then leaving ghost

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, devenv

I'm developing a C#/WPF application using Visual Studio. This app uses a com port, then releases it upon exit. I'm using the debugger to run and stop this application often. Sometimes, I get an exception when starting up a debug session saying that the com port is already in use.

The code always closes the open com port on exit, so I ran portmon to see who was holding on to the port. It turns out that in "normal" cases, the port is grabbed, used, and closed by my application (Process KaleidoscopeApp in portmon). In the case where the port is not released, the port is being used by process "devenv", which is Visual Studio itself.

Why is devenv the owner of the com port in these cases? When I close the app, why does it continue to hold it? Only when I close Visual Studio is the port released. It is strange behavior especially since the debugger has specifically halted within Visual Studio.

Here is a capture from portmon showing access to the com port. You can see a typical session begins with IRP_MJ_CREATE and ends with IRP_MJ_CLOSE. This is always the case with KaleidoscopeApp. You can see the last bit is run by devenv. Yet each launch is always in the VS debugger.

---

> 357   0.11112275  KaleidoscopeApp IRP_MJ_CREATE   Serial4 SUCCESS Options:
>   Open
>   358   0.00000305  KaleidoscopeApp IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_PROPERTIES Serial4 SUCCESS
>   ...
>
> 406   0.02997366  KaleidoscopeApp IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  Serial4 SUCCESS
>   407   0.03390231  KaleidoscopeApp IRP_MJ_CLOSE    Serial4 SUCCESS
>   408   0.11443431  KaleidoscopeApp IRP_MJ_CREATE   Serial4 SUCCESS Options:
>   Open
>   409   0.00000727  KaleidoscopeApp IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_PROPERTIES Serial4 SUCCESS
>   ...
>
> 457   0.02995160  KaleidoscopeApp IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  Serial4 SUCCESS
>   458   0.03389956  KaleidoscopeApp IRP_MJ_CLOSE    Serial4 SUCCESS
>   459   0.11307261  devenv.exe  IRP_MJ_CREATE   Serial4 SUCCESS Options:
>   Open
>   460   0.00000185  devenv.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_PROPERTIES Serial4 SUCCESS
>   ...
>
> 501   35.55274341 devenv.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK   Serial4 CANCELLED

---

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I have had this same problem, but with files instead.  It has something to do with the debugger environment, but what I'm not sure.

Comment: Was it a "it fixed itself" situation? Do remember if you changed any settings?

Comment: This is a bit too bizarre.  SerialPort.Close() is very prone to deadlock when you use Invoke() in a DataReceived event handler.  At least eliminate the possible deadlock, just don't call Close().  It isn't necessary.

Comment: My DataReceived handler simply enqueues incoming bytes and triggers an AutoResetEvent. There doesn't seem to be any deadlocking going on. I'm fairly sure this is related to the Visual Studio debugger. I'll post up a capture from portmon.

Comment: Start Visual Studio with the devenv.exe /safemode option so you can be sure it is not some kind of add-on that is grabbing the port.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem these last weeks, with VS2008 and VS2010. One way to fix it is to delete the .suo file from the solution folder.

For which reason VS is doing that, and why it's stored in the .suo file? I don't know...